# SharpSvn GetFileVersions and GetContentStream throws InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, sharpsvn

I'm trying to use SharpSvn to get the contents of a file at a particular revision.  I have the following code:

```
var svnClient = new SvnClient();
var revisionInfo = new SvnFileVersionsArgs
    {
        Start = 80088,
        End = 80093
    };

Collection<SvnFileVersionEventArgs> fileVersions;
svnClient.GetFileVersions(
    new SvnUriTarget("https://DbDiff.svn.codeplex.com/svn/DbDiffCommon/DataAccess/SqlCommand11.xml"), 
    revisionInfo,
    out fileVersions);

var stream =  fileVersions[0].GetContentStream();
```

However on the last line I'm getting the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  Message=This method can only be invoked from the eventhandler handling this eventargs instance
  Source=SharpSvn
  StackTrace:
       at SharpSvn.SvnFileVersionEventArgs.GetContentStream(SvnFileVersionWriteArgs args) in g:\dist\src\sharpsvn\commands\fileversions.cpp:line 545
       at SharpSvn.SvnFileVersionEventArgs.GetContentStream() in g:\dist\src\sharpsvn\commands\fileversions.cpp:line 534
       at SharpSvnFileVersions.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\temp\SharpSvnFileVersions\Program.cs:line 29
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

How should I go about getting the contents of the file at each revision?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I can use `SvnClient.Write()` to grab the file contents:

```
SvnClient svnClient = new SvnClient();
SvnUriTarget target = new SvnUriTarget("https://DbDiff.svn.codeplex.com/svn/DbDiffCommon/DataAccess/SqlCommand11.xml", 80088);

Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
svnClient.Write(target, stream);
```

Comment: If you just need one version of a file then this is the way to go. The FileVersions() api is a speedup when you need many versions of one file, but the codeplex subversion proxy doesn't implement the api for this properly.

Answer (score 0):

GetFileVersions is only useful for specific scenarios. Subversion itself uses it to implement blame. I happened to create this test program for a different scenario: migrate all revisions of one file to a new repository. Posting it here for others to use.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using SharpSvn;
using SharpSvn.UI;

class SvnDumpFileToRepository
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Uri uri = null;
        if (args.Length < 2
            || !Uri.TryCreate(args[0], UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Usage: SvnDumpFileToRepository URL PATH");
        }

        using (SvnRepositoryClient repos = new SvnRepositoryClient())
        {
            repos.CreateRepository(args[1]);
        }

        Uri reposUri = SvnTools.LocalPathToUri(args[1], true);

        using (SvnClient client = new SvnClient())
        using (SvnClient client2 = new SvnClient())
        {
            SvnUI.Bind(client, new SvnUIBindArgs());

            string fileName = SvnTools.GetFileName(uri);
            bool create = true;
            client.FileVersions(uri,
                delegate(object sender, SvnFileVersionEventArgs e)
                {
                    Console.Write("Copying {0} in r{1}", fileName, e.Revision);

                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        e.WriteTo(ms); // Write full text to memory stream
                        ms.Position = 0;

                        // And now use 'svnmucc' to update repository
                        client2.RepositoryOperation(reposUri,
                            new SvnRepositoryOperationArgs { LogMessage = e.LogMessage },
                            delegate(SvnMultiCommandClient mucc)
                            {
                                if (create)
                                {
                                    mucc.CreateFile(fileName, ms);
                                    create = false;
                                }
                                else
                                    mucc.UpdateFile(fileName, ms);
                            });
                    }
                });
        }
    }
}
```